# Binding Existential types in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, existential-type

This is my basic CMap which map classes (Class[T] for any T) to any type of value.

```
scala> type CMap = Map[Class[T] forSome{type T}, Any]
defined type alias CMap

scala> val cMap: CMap = Map(classOf[Int]->5, classOf[String]->"abc", classOf[Double]->"ddd")
cMap: CMap = Map(int -> 5, class java.lang.String -> abc, double -> ddd)
```

Now I want a "bound" CMap (call it CMapBind). Like CMap, it maps classes (any classes) to values (any values). But unlike the CMap, CMapBind has a type binding between the key and value, meaning I hope the following behavior:

```
val cMapBind: CMapBind = Map(classOf[Int]->5, classOf[String]-> "aa") // should compile
val cMapBind: CMapBind = Map(classOf[Int]->5, classOf[String]-> 0)    // should fail compile
```

How do I implement CMapBind?

I know the following two won't work syntactically/logically.

```
scala> type CMapBind = Map[Class[T] forSome{type T}, T]
<console>:8: error: not found: type T
       type CMapBind = Map[Class[T] forSome{type T}, T]


scala> type CMapBind = Map[Class[T], T] forSome{type T}
scala> val cMapBind: CMapBind = Map(classOf[Int]->5, classOf[String]->"str")
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[Class[_ >: String with Int],Any]
 required: CMapBind
    (which expands to)  Map[Class[T],T] forSome { type T }
       val cMapBind: CMapBind = Map(classOf[Int]->5, classOf[String]->"str")
```

Note that here I am using type constructor Class[T] as an example to illustrate the question. In my code I have my own types, e.g. `trait Animal[S, T], class Dog extends Animal[Int, String]`.

Edit 1: 
I should have mentioned that I am using immutable Map as an example, but what I really need is a mutable heterogeneous Map).

Comment: See https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/90b05abc061b2a677179d89aa64156b48a8a6afb/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/util/TypedMultiMap.scala

Comment: Not sure it is possible (in a way you want to do it), due to type erasure. This map will always loose the value type (to upper bound `Any`), and the key type will always be mixing. Think you need a sort of heterogeneous `Map`, to save types.

Comment: yeah, heterogeneous Map like `HMap` from `shapeless` is what I am looking at.

Comment: It is not possible for you to use shapeless, you want to use your own? Because with shapeless it is extremely nice :)

Comment: I would love to use `shapeless`'s `HMap` if it works. In my application I want a "mutable" hetergenous Map. My understanding is that `HMap` is immutable.

Comment: The default scala `Map` is immutable too. It is possible to use immutable with `var` (I mean `var hm: HMap[Mapping]`, the type depends on implicits in scope of `get` function of `shapeless` get). Or it is important to have a mutable HMap (like `scala.collection.mutable.Map`)?

Comment: By `mutable`, I do mean the `Map` itself, regardless of the created object  assigned to a `val` or `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to implement mutable `HMap`. Some explanations about Scala type system is here by @MilesSabin: http://www.chuusai.com/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/

The idea is to statically check the constructor (here you will see, that it's arity depends on your hands, so it is possible to generate it or smth else), and the insert method. By the way, same way immutable `HMap` implemented in shapeless.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

class HMapBuilder[R[_, _]] { // constructor arity is two
  def apply[K1, V1](e1: (K1, V1))(implicit ev1: R[K1, V1]) = 
    new HMap[R](Map(e1))
  def apply[K1, V1, K2, V2](e1: (K1, V1), e2: (K2, V2))
                           (implicit ev1: R[K1, V1], ev2: R[K2, V2]) =
    new HMap[R](Map(e1, e2))
}
```

So it is a constructor of our map. Evidences will statically check types of the inserting data. Next, lets wrap the default scala collection:

```
class HMap[R[_, _]](underlying : Map[Any, Any] = Map.empty) {
  def get[K, V](k : K)(implicit ev : R[K, V]) : Option[V] = 
    underlying.get(k).asInstanceOf[Option[V]]

  def +=[K, V](kv : (K, V))(implicit ev : R[K, V]) : HMap[R] = {
    underlying += kv
    this
  }
  def -=[K](k : K) : HMap[R] = {
    underlying -= k
    this
  }

  override def toString = underlying.toString
}
```

Finally wrapping `HMapBuilder`, to make a pleasant constructor:

```
object HMap {
  def apply[R[_, _]] = new HMapBuilder[R]

  def empty[R[_, _]] = new HMap[R]
  def empty[R[_, _]](underlying : Map[Any, Any]) = 
    new HMap[R](underlying)
}
```

In result, the usage is similar to `shapeless` `HMap`:

```
class Mapping[K, V]

implicit def mappingFromClass[A] = new Mapping[Class[A], A]

val hm = HMap[Mapping](classOf[Int] -> 5) // ok
hm += (classOf[String] -> "string") // ok
hm += (classOf[Boolean] -> false) // ok
hm += (classOf[Double] -> "sss") // compile fail
```

Works as expected. I implemented only insert and remove functions, other functions is possible to define same way.